# ANTLR Not Emitting Error Messages on Invalid Input

Tags: antlr, antlr3, antlrworks

I have begun learning ANTLR in order to implement a domain-specific language (DSL) in the future. I have purchased The Definitive ANTLR Reference and have begun working my way through it in order to familiarize myself with the program and the concepts of languages/compiler design. I have successfully gotten everything working within my environment (Visual Studio 2010 and C#), and I have successfully been able to create some basic grammars, as described throughout the book. Source code for java can be found here: http://pragprog.com/titles/tpantlr/source_code

However, while working through Chapter 3, I have come across a problem involving the classes not emitting errors to the console, as it shows in the book. I am using the same grammar that is used in the book, so I am assuming it has something to do with the C# runtimes. I am currently using ANTLRWorks to generate the lexer/parser, and I am using the 3.4 ANTLR distribution runtimes for CSharp3 (Antlr3.Runtime.dll and Antlr4.StringTemplate.dll).

Is this a known issue? If not, should I try using an older version of the runtimes or ANTLRWorks?

The grammar I am using:

```
grammar Expr;

options
{
   language = CSharp3;
}

prog    :   stat+ ;

stat    :   expr NEWLINE
|   ID '=' expr NEWLINE
|       NEWLINE
;

expr    :   multExpr (('+'|'-') multExpr)*
;

multExpr 
:   atom('*' atom)*
;

atom    :   INT
|   ID
|   '(' expr ')'
;

ID  :   ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z')+ ;
INT :   '0'..'9'+ ;
NEWLINE :   '\r'? '\n';
WS  :   (' '|'\t')+ {Skip();};
```

I will post the C# classes if anyone needs to see them, but they are very long, so I will hold off until someone requests them. Thank you.

Comment: What is the input you _don't_ get errors with?

Comment: I am not getting errors for any invalid input. I have tried things like "3+@", with no error. "(3" also results in no error. It appears that it isn't a specific type of exception that is causing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've only worked with the CSharp2 target (and runtime) because I've not been able to get the  CSharp3 target running on my Ubuntu-machine with MonoDevelop.

When you use ANTLRWorks, the `org.antlr.Tool` is used to generate the `ExprLexer.cs` and `ExprParser.cs` classes, which the CSharp3 runtime has (sometimes?) issues with, if memory serves me well.

Try generating the `.cs` source files with the `Antlr3.exe` tool instead: http://www.tunnelvisionlabs.com/downloads/antlr/antlr-dotnet-tool-3.4.1.9004.7z *(note that tunnelvisionlabs.com is from [the author](https://stackoverflow.com/users/138304/280z28) of the CSharp3 target)*.

I haven't tested this, because of my unfamiliarity with the CSharp3 target, but it's worth a try.

Comment: I've given this a try, but I'm still getting the same results. I guess I will try rolling back to an early version of ANTLR and seeing if that solves it. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Well I've rolled back to ANTLR 3.1.1 and I am getting error messages, so it appears to be working, albeit not exactly how I was expecting. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 4):

After some debugging on 3.4.1.9004 source code, I found that the traceDestination property was null.  So, I set the property as shown below in Main() and messages started showing up on the console.

parser.TraceDestination = Console.Out;